# Windows has frequent BSoD with sound cards

Tags: windows-7, audio, bsod

I recently bought an Asus Xonar DSX sound card, installed and set up the device and then found my Windows machine would blue screen very frequently, after following the Asus troubleshooting and many forum threads, I found nothing to fix it and figured it must have been a faulty card, so I sent it back and got a Creative SoundBlaster Z. Same issue. I reinstalled Windows and had a good couple of weeks with no BSoD, but now it has started happening again with most dump files pointing to ntoskrnl.exe. I also dual boot Debian on this same computer and have had no problems at all in Linux, only Windows. It is Windows 7 64bit Professional and fully updated Creative drivers from their website.
Any ideas on how I can fix this?

UPDATE:
Here is the most recent dmp file from a BSoD
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4H6mY31LFBJYXJObThFVkZPbzg

Comment: After you used windbg what did your analysis show?

Comment: Hi, I don't think I used windbg, I read the dump files with BSoD viewer, a separate program I downloaded. Is this the same sort of thing or am I mistaken?

Comment: windbg can provide the exact driver causing the problem if it's being caused by a device driver

Comment: Ah OK, I'll try that and update my question once I have more info, thanks

Comment: Windbg can be tricky to use for some people. If you can't figure it out, upload the .dmp file and let us know you did so.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay - things seemed to be going ok until today! Couldn't work windbg out so have posted a link to the dmp file in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an update. I ended up doing a move around of hardware in my PC when moving to a new case, I put the sound card in a different PCi-e slot and the crashes seems to go away. Later on I put the card back in the old slot again and my crashes started again. I have since replaced the PCi-e card with a PCI Asus Xonar DS and have had no issues. Looks like a bad PCi-e slot.